# Can I power RGB LED strips with only the positive charge from a battery?

Tags: led-strip

I'm looking to make this really cool model that I can 3D print. I have the RGB LED strips that I need as they are extras from my gaming setup.

The GOVEE LED lights have only a positive charge to them, and instead of buying a bunch of adapters, I was wondering if I could only use the positive nipple (which is what I call them) of the battery to power them?

Comment: Can you upload some pictures of your equipment, especially the items you don’t have the correct names for?

Comment: what about the negative terminal on the battery?

Comment: what does this mean? ... `The GOVEE LED lights has only a positive charge to them`

Comment: Which Govee LED lights do you have? Do they look like this:- https://www.reddit.com/r/Govee/comments/s69v2s/govee_rgb_teardown_hacks_red_is_not_working_so/

Answer (score 2):

LEDs are current devices and with just a positive or negative charge they will do nothing. In order to have the correct amount of current flow through them. Many times this is accomplished with a resistor in series with the batteries + and - terminals. Many light strips have several LEDs connected in series with a resistor. By hooking up just the + you do not have a complete path for the current to flow so it will not light. Also they have a forward voltage requirement and if that is not met they will also not light. Using the link you provided they require either 12V or 24V, that indicates it needs both a + and - connection. If I am wrong please post a link showing how they run with only a + connection.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a stupid question.  The remote uses the RGB connections to the ground using pulse modulated grounding with transistor switches to vary the intensity and blend colors.  The repetition rate is often 1 to 5 kHz so it is flicker-free then the duty cycle can be 0 to 100%.

There are other simple ways to fake this if you wanted a simple circuit with a few parts.  [for example this sequence](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjAbCAMB00IQVnAZngTgOwBYxNQCYxoAOMUiMEJaGmupAUwFowwAoSVcCOwrIRCEywwTBA4JjGBwAyw0qRCpUUQkpURldagDMAhgBsAzk3rQOAJV51U0KeyH3Hw8ImGwUhL9K8cAd3AMIUIcXRDwMCFLSCEwSKdgoQgpIQB7IwATFiymQwBXIwAXFiMmLPBpGHhOACdkkFSolKl%20Wg4Acxamx2ieuliIULCewlHm%20IA5VDaqwdquYeEkKCTCVd63MBm53RroTiCE1uEJtsCzqUnN5stK8bTwq%20FRITzCko4HzbD29TeIA%20BiKxUuGzWfBWAJ04NGImUj3AOAuQSR61GYBRsjRm3WeKhliAA) (except inverted with +12 and RGB transistors)

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgVKel.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>